# Generate a PNG QRCode using Python

Tags: python, png, qr-code

I am trying to create a .png of a QRCode using Python. However, I am having difficulty. When I run this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import pyqrcode
from tkinter.font import Font
import random

def generateQR():
    num=random.randint(1,2)
    if num==1:
        QRCode=pyqrcode.create("You Win!")
        QRCode.png("QRCode.png",scale=8)
        print("done")

generateQR()
```

The QRCode.png file is not readable; however, the .svg version is (using Internet Explorer).

I have read https://pypi.org/project/PyQRCode/ and have seen the use of the `pypng` module. However, I have tried this and the resultant .png was still unreadable.

Comment: Not readable as in the png doesn't display? Or that the code can not be read by a decoder? If it can't be read by the decoder, make the scale larger. SVG tend to not have their size given and end up scaled up to the size of their container.

Comment: It seems that you use recursive call to function with this formatting.

Comment: After installing `pyqrcode` and `pypng` with pip, I was able to generate a valid png file without any problems (using the same two lines of code in your function). What program are you using to read/display the png?

Comment: Confirm that after installing `pyqrcode` and `pypng`, I have created `png`, `svg` and console representations of QR code. Tested the link with my phone QR code scanner. All works as expected.

Comment: You can post the `png` image as part of the question. It will be obvious if it has some flaws.

Comment: @ekhumoro I am using the Window's photo app.

Comment: @ЯрославМашко I cannot post my image as it is not a valid image for Stack Overflow. The site says it is not readable. Could someone post there code and I'll see if it produces a valid image?

Comment: @LyraOrwell The code we used is exactly the same as what is currently shown in your question. Are you sure you're looking at the right file? Try opening the file with PIL: `img = Image.open('QRCode.png')`. Do you get any errors? If not, display it with `img.show()`. What do you see?